# create several charts in Excel with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, loops, charts

I have a worksheet with 300 columns and would like to create one scatter plot for each column, bringing data from two other sheets that are in the same worksheet. 
The problem is that I´m not familiar with VBA, and some error codes don't help at all.

```
Private Sub Create_Charts()
   Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim chrt As Chart

    For i = 1 To 300

        Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Graphs")
        Set chrt = sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
        With chrt
            'Data
            .ChartType = xlXYScatter
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Scatter Chart"""


            'With the following parameters it works:
            '.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=OP!$c$4:$c$1588"
            '.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=PV!$c$4:$c$1588"

            'But I need something like this:                
            .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = CStr(Worksheets("PV").Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 1588)))
            .SeriesCollection(1).Values = CStr(Worksheets("OV").Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 1588)))

            'Location
            .ChartArea.Left = 380 * i - 380
            .ChartArea.Top = 100
            .ChartArea.Height = 360
            .ChartArea.Width = 360

            'Formatting
            .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
            .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True
            .HasAxis(xlCategory, xlPrimary) = False
            .HasAxis(xlValue, xlPrimary) = False

            .HasLegend = False


        End With

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [mcve].

Comment: What exactly does the error code say and what line does it stop on?

Comment: " I have a worksheet with 300 columns and would like to create one scatter plot for each column, bringing data from two other sheets that are in the same worksheet ". I thought this was clear enough.

Comment: The code error was "Run-time error ´1004': Application-defined or object-defined error". But I think I was having other errors, so I did not add in here. Anyway, it´s solved. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line references a column:

```
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=OP!$c$4:$c$1588"
```

This references a row, row i from column 4 to column 1588:

```
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = CStr(Worksheets("PV").Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 1588)))
```

But you also need to reference not only Range but Cells. And if you pass in a string address, you need the leading "="; it's easier to pass in a range. So try this:

```
Dim wsPV As Worksheet, wsOV As Worksheet
Dim rngX As Range, rngY As Range

Set wsPV = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PV")
Set wsOV = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("OV")

Set rngX = wsPV.Range(wsPV.Cells(4, i), wsPV.Cells(1588, i)
Set rngY = wsOV.Range(wsOV.Cells(4, i), wsOV.Cells(1588, i)

chrt.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = rngX
chrt.SeriesCollection(1).Values = rngY
```

Comment: Glad to help. Why not mark it answered, or upvote it? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry! forgot.. done! I can't upvote due to my reputation, by the way.